# How to open multiple URLs with cURL without delay

Tags: php, url, curl

I was wondering if it's possible to open multiple URLs with cURL or maybe something else.

I tried this until now.

```
$urls = array(
          "http://google.com",
          "http://youtube.com",
          );

foreach($urls as $url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 200);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

The 200ms are there to let the site open fully.
Maybe you know any alternatives.

Is it possible to open multiple URLs in PHP at the same time? Not client sided, server side.

Comment: I think [curl_multi](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php) does what you need. Instead of `curl_exec` you should add the handles to a `curl_multi` handle and then do a `curl_mutli_exec`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution would be simultaneous cURL HTTP requests.
For faster implementation, you can use this function (thanks to [phpied](https://www.phpied.com/simultaneuos-http-requests-in-php-with-curl/)):

```
function multiRequest($data, $options = array()) {

  // array of curl handles
  $curly = array();
  // data to be returned
  $result = array();

  // multi handle
  $mh = curl_multi_init();

  // loop through $data and create curl handles
  // then add them to the multi-handle
  foreach ($data as $id => $d) {

    $curly[$id] = curl_init();

    $url = (is_array($d) && !empty($d['url'])) ? $d['url'] : $d;
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_HEADER,         0);
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // post?
    if (is_array($d)) {
      if (!empty($d['post'])) {
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POST,       1);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $d['post']);
      }
    }

    // extra options?
    if (!empty($options)) {
      curl_setopt_array($curly[$id], $options);
    }

    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curly[$id]);
  }

  // execute the handles
  $running = null;
  do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
  } while($running > 0);


  // get content and remove handles
  foreach($curly as $id => $c) {
    $result[$id] = curl_multi_getcontent($c);
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $c);
  }

  // all done
  curl_multi_close($mh);

  return $result;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
$data = array(
  'http://search.yahooapis.com/VideoSearchService/V1/videoSearch?appid=YahooDemo&query=Pearl+Jam&output=json',
  'http://search.yahooapis.com/ImageSearchService/V1/imageSearch?appid=YahooDemo&query=Pearl+Jam&output=json',
  'http://search.yahooapis.com/AudioSearchService/V1/artistSearch?appid=YahooDemo&artist=Pearl+Jam&output=json'
);
$r = multiRequest($data);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($r);
```

Hope it helps.
Also [read this](https://www.phpied.com/simultaneuos-http-requests-in-php-with-curl/).

Comment: But I still have a little question. It doesn't have to do with the other question above. Is it possible to ignore the reponse time of a websites? Like after five seconds it just goes on and doesn't wait for the response of the website.

Comment: Yep, you still able to use CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS.
Just apply it after `curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);` in that function.

Comment: Thank you very much. Everything is working how I wanted to! I'll give you some credits :) With best regards

Comment: Happy to help ;)